# FTS5 cannot use Operators with Match operator

Tags: ios, sqlite, match, operator-keyword, fts5

I'm doing full text search using sqlite and below are some select query examples that I'm using.

Ex:

1. SELECT * FROM table WHERE table MATCH 'column:father* OR for*' ORDER BY rank;
2. SELECT * FROM table WHERE table MATCH 'column:exam* AND yo*' ORDER BY rank;

These queries are not working properly. Giving me all the rows in the database as the result. I cannot use AND/OR with the Match operator when using asterisk. Any solutions?

Thanks.

Comment: Please post your virtual table definition.

Comment: CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tableName USING FTS5(column1, column2);